# DateTimeFormatter Cannot Parse Dates Without Leading Zeroes in German

Tags: java, localization, java-time

Our client found an interesting bug today. Consider the following method:

```
final DateTimeFormatter englishFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("04/01/17", englishFormatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("4/1/17", englishFormatter));

final DateTimeFormatter germanFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("01.04.17", germanFormatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1.4.17", germanFormatter));
```

(If you don't know, these are indeed correct dates in English and German. I'd even say they're the same date [April 1 2017]. Take a moment to consider what you'd think this application should return.)

What it does return is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1.4.17' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

The English date format works with and without leading zeroes. The German format works only with leading zeroes.

I can't seem to find a property to change this behavior to work correctly.

How can I make the `DateTimeFormatter` understand German dates without leading zeroes?

**Note:** Our application supports multiple locales, so using a specific `DateTimeFormatter` (like `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d.M.yy")`) is completely out of the question, especially since we want to parse the *default* date format.

Comment: Please take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816016/how-to-parse-non-standard-month-names-with-datetimeformatter

Comment: @vinS That is exactly the opposite of what I want. I want to parse the standard German date.

Comment: I tried your code with JDK-9. It returns me similar exception with three minor differences:
java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1988)
java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1890)
java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:428)
I think you can't resolve this without checking your string.

Comment: There is not only one single standard German date. In reality, Germans use many forms so you cannot totally rely on single formats.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the opposite: formatting the date with your localized formatters.

```
    LocalDate testDate = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.APRIL, 1);

    final DateTimeFormatter englishFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println("English: " + testDate.format(englishFormatter));

    final DateTimeFormatter germanFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                .withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    System.out.println("German: " + testDate.format(germanFormatter));
```

I got

> ```
> English: 4/1/17
> German:  01.04.17
> ```

So it’s quite clear that Java thinks that standard German date formatting uses leading zeroes. If you are certain that this is wrong, you may consider filing a bug with Oracle.

To circumvent the behaviour you don’t like, with multiple locales I am afraid you will need some sort of hack. The best hack I could think of was the following. It’s not beautiful. It works.

```
private static final Map<Locale, DateTimeFormatter> STEFFI_S_LOCALIZED_FORMATTERS
        = createSteffiSFormatters();

private static Map<Locale, DateTimeFormatter> createSteffiSFormatters() {
    Map<Locale, DateTimeFormatter> formatters = new HashMap<>(2);
    formatters.put(Locale.GERMAN, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d.M.uu"));
    return formatters;
}

public static DateTimeFormatter getLocalizedFormatter(Locale formattingLocale) {
    DateTimeFormatter localizedFormatter
            = STEFFI_S_LOCALIZED_FORMATTERS.get(formattingLocale);
    if (localizedFormatter == null) {
        localizedFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                                              .withLocale(formattingLocale);
    }
    return localizedFormatter;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
    final DateTimeFormatter englishFormatter = getLocalizedFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("04/01/17", englishFormatter));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("4/1/17", englishFormatter));

    final DateTimeFormatter germanFormatter = getLocalizedFormatter(Locale.GERMAN);
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("01.04.17", germanFormatter));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1.4.17", germanFormatter));
```

This prints:

```
2017-04-01
2017-04-01
2017-04-01
2017-04-01
```

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be an assumption about German cultural norms including a padding zero. Some internet searching shows that the modern approach in Germany proper is generally to include the padding zero when representing in all digits (no month name). Past traditional habits may have varied, as do other German-related places. So this behavior in Java appears to be a feature, not a bug — but some folks may expect other behavior. Wikipedia: [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) and [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Europe).

Comment: @BasilBourque Indeed, just a feature and not a bug. Java relies here on CLDR-data, and they had to choose one wide-spread variation with preference to [German DIN-norm 5008](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datumsformat). This is also what I feel most common (as my mother language is German).

Comment: @BasilBourque I don't know about the feature thing - the old API supported both date formats: `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.GERMAN).parse("1.4.17")` And the Wiki articles both state that the zero was only used as padding and both are possible.

Comment: @SteffiS. The old `DateFormat` accepted a wealth of incorrect input, this was most often a nuissance because you didn’t catch bugs. You’ve found a way to exploit it as a feature.

Comment: @OleV.V. "Exploit" is a pretty harsh word for "allowing the date format that comes naturally to most people".

Comment: Sorry about my clumsy English, @SteffiS.

Comment: You can find the "default" date formats for various locales in the  `sun.text.resources` resource bundles.  For Germany, see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/text/resources/de/FormatData_de.java?av=f.  I haven't looked at java 9 or other java implementation but suspect it would be similar.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to trap the DateTimeParseException and then try again with a modified/reduced date pattern.

```
import java.text.Format;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.IsoChronology;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.ListResourceBundle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Locale[] locales = {Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.GERMAN};
        for (Locale locale : locales)
        {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(locale);
            String [] englishDates = {"01/04/17","1/4/17"};
            String [] germanDates = {"01.04.17","1.4.17"};

            String datePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT,null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
            System.out.println("Locale " + locale.getDisplayName() + ": Default Date Pattern (short): " + datePattern);

            String[] dates = null;

            if (locale == Locale.ENGLISH)
                dates = englishDates;
            else
                dates = germanDates;

            for (String date : dates) {
                try {
                    System.out.printf("  " + date + " -> ");
                    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(date, formatter));
                }
                catch (DateTimeParseException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error!");
                    // Try alternate pattern
                    datePattern = datePattern.replace("dd", "d").replace("MM", "M");
                    System.out.println("  Modified Date Pattern (short): " + datePattern);
                    // Allow single digits in day and month
                    DateTimeFormatter modifiedFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern);
                    System.out.println("  " + date + " -> " + LocalDate.parse(date, modifiedFormatter));  // OK
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives:

```
Locale English: Default Date Pattern (short): M/d/yy
  01/04/17 -> 2017-01-04
  1/4/17 -> 2017-01-04
Locale German: Default Date Pattern (short): dd.MM.yy
  01.04.17 -> 2017-04-01
  1.4.17 -> Error!
  Modified Date Pattern (short): d.M.yy
  1.4.17 -> 2017-04-01
```

Comment: I even suspect that using the reduced pattern from the outset would work.

Comment: This will work for all locales using two-digit day-og-month and/or month (not only German). The OP will have to decide whether this is desired; it could be an advantage. If it is indeed desired, your solution seems less of a hack than mine.